# Unix/bash: For loops with grep to collapse rows

Tags: bash, unix, for-loop, grep

I have a tab separated fileA that looks like this:

```
nameA     GO:0005737     cytoplasm
nameB     GO:0005875     microtubule associated complex
nameB     GO:0005884     actin filament
nameC     GO:0005737     cytoplasm
nameC     GO:0005856     cytoskeleton
nameC     GO:0005524     ATP binding

..
```

The first column is a gene name, the second is a GO id and the third is a description of that id. There can be one or several lines for each identifier in the first column.

I would like to make a new file where each gene name is just one row and all associated GO terms are in the second column and the descriptions in the third:

```
nameA    GO:0005737    cytoplasm
nameB    GO:0005875,GO:0005884,    microtubule associated complex, actin filament
nameC    GO:0005737, GO:0005856, GO:0005524    cytoplasm, cytoskeleton, ATP binding
...
```

...and the order of GO id follows the order of description terms i.e. first GO id in each row corresponds to the first description term.

I tried getting a unique list of all the gene names, then running a for loop grepping for each gene name, cutting out the GO column and replacing newline with comma, then adding a new line at the end.

```
cut -f1 fileA | uniq > identifiers

for name in `cat identifiers`
do
    grep "$name" fileA | cut -f2 | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/$/\n/' >> GOs_collapsed
done
```

After this I plan on doing the same for the third column, then using paste to get the two together with the identifier file.

However, this bash script above does not work. The output in GOs_collapsed is just a list of GO:s just like before.

```
GO:0005737
GO:0005875
GO:0005884
..
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with awk one liner as below:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
       FS=OFS="\t"
     } 
     { if (a[$1] == "") { 
          a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$3 
       } else { 
           a[$1]=a[$1] "," $2; b[$1]=b[$1] "," $3;
       } 
     } END { 
         for (i in a) 
             print i "\t" a[i] "\t" b[i] 
     }' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Hardly a "one-liner" though!

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Is it possible to generalize this to an input file with an additional column? Like a second description column to the right of the first one.

Comment: That would be `$4`. What do you want to do with it? Merge with `$3`? Then `b[$1] = b[$1] "," $4`. (The variable names could be less opaque.)

Comment: I'd like to have it as a fourth column in the output file.

Comment: Perhaps I can just add a variable like `a[$1]=a[$1] "," $2; b[$1]=b[$1] "," $3; c[$1]=c[$1] "," $4; ` ?

Answer (score 1):

Read all entries for one key and print the collected output when you see a new key. This requires all entries for one key to be adjacent, which is easily facilitated by sorting the input.

```
IFS=$'\t'
sort fileA |
while read -r key go desc; do
    if [ "$key" != "$prev" ] && [ "$prev" != "" ]; then
        printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$prev" "${gos#,}" "${descs#,}"
        gos=""
        descs=""
    fi
    gos="$gos,$go"
    descs="$descs,$desc"
    prev="$key"
done
printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$key" "${gos#,}" "${descs#,}"
```

The construct `${var#prefix}` returns the value of `var` with any `prefix` removed. Allowing and expecting a leading comma simplifies the main flow, so we don't have to special-case the first round for a new key.

Notice also the piping into a `while` loop, which avoids both the temporary file and the pesky `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is sorted on the first field of each line this should do what you want.

```
$ cat group.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}

function printline(last, col, cols) {
    printf last
    for (i = 2; i <= cols; i++) {
        printf OFS"%s", col[i]
    }
    printf ORS
}

$1 != last {
    if (last) {
        printline(last, col, cols)
    }

    # Reset last and our accumulated fields.
    last=$1
    split("", col)
}

$1 == last {
    cols = (cols > NF) ? cols : NF
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
        col[i] = col[i] (col[i]?",":"") $i
    }
    next
}

END {
    printline(last, col, cols)
}
$ awk -f group.awk fileA
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you had so far:

```
cut -f1 -d' '  fileA | uniq | while read name; do
    awk -v name="$name" '$1 == name {print $2}' fileA | paste -s -d','  > GOs
    echo "$name    $(awk -v name="$name" '$1 == name {print $3}' fileA | paste -s -d',' | paste GOs -)"
done
```

Change `cut -d1 -d' '` to `cut -f1` if the fields are separated by tabs rather than spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically you could do it this way.

```
for name in `cut  -d' ' -f 1 file.txt | uniq`
do
    line="$name\t"
    grepVal=`grep "$name" file.txt`
    for val in `grep "$name" file.txt | cut -d' ' -f6`
    do
            line="$line$val, "
    done
    line="$line\t"
    for desc in `grep "$name" file.txt | cut -d' ' -f 11-36`
    do
            line="$line$desc, "
    done
    echo $line >> GOs_collapsed
done
```

Output

```
nameA   GO:0005737,     cytoplasm,
nameB   GO:0005875, GO:0005884,     microtubule, associated, complex, actin, filament,
nameC   GO:0005737, GO:0005856, GO:0005524,     cytoplasm, cytoskeleton, ATP, binding,
```